# present SwiftUI view from a SKScene

Tags: swiftui, sprite-kit

Is it possible to present a SwiftUI view from a SpriteKit scene?
I have various sprites in the game scene. When certain one receive touch data I want a SwiftUI view to pop up.

In the past I have used something like this to present another UI view.

```
  if bloqsLogo.contains(location) {
                if instructionsOn == false {
                    let pop = InstructionsPopUp()
                    pop.tag = 104
                    self.view?.addSubview(pop)
                    instructionsOn = true
                } else
                    if instructionsOn == true {
                        if let viewWithTag = self.view!.viewWithTag(104) {
                            viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
                            instructionsOn = false 
                        }else{
                            print("nah")
                        }
                }
                
                
            }
```

My SKScene is an instance of another SwiftUI view and presented there. A good part of my GUI is done in SwiftUI. I am basically wanting to code as much of my App as I can in SwiftUI while keeping the physics and sprites in a SKScene. All of which is going rather well besides this!